# Crystal report converting DateTime to string Too many arguments have been given to this function

Tags: c#, datetime, crystal-reports

I have a simple formula like below in crystal report:

```
iif(isnull({employ.createdDate}),"", ToText({employ.createdDate}, "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

The `{employ.createdDate}` is in below format:

```
02/09/2015 10:48:25
```

It works fine when `{employ.createdDate}` is null, but when it's not null, the below error message shows:

```
  Too many arguments have been given to this function 
  Error in File employeeInfo.rpt: 
  Error in formula txtDate
```

Removing the "dd-MMM-yyyy" does solve the problem but I would like to format the date to "dd-MMM-yyyy" format i.e. `"09-FEB-2015"`

What's wrong with the formula?

Comment: What is the definition of `iif` method?

Comment: @SonerGönül It's a crystal report build in formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I figured it out...

The `02/09/2015 10:48:25` is in string format, so I need to convert it to date and convert it to string, I modified the formula to this, and it works:

```
ToText(cDate({employ.createdDate}),"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver! i had the exact same issue but with an integer

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead of just toText

iif(isnull({employ.createdDate}),"", ToText(cDate({employ.createdDate}),"dd-MMM-yyyy"))