# Crystal Report convert date parameter format

Tags: date, crystal-reports-2010

I have a stored procedure that takes three parameters, `@IsPaid`, `@StartDate` & `@EndDate`, and the format of these dates comes in as text like `2017010` & `20170711`.

I am trying to create a Formula field that will display something like `01/01/2017 - 07/11/2017` when `@IsPaid` is true.

Using the following I can get the Formula Field to display `20170101 - 20170711`.

```
if {?@IsPaid} = "true" then {?@ReportStartDate} + " - " + {?@ReportEndDate}
```

The issue I am having is when I try to convert the format of the date.  I have tried the following as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473746/crystal-report-converting-datetime-to-string-too-many-arguments-have-been-given):

```
if {?@IsPaid} = "true" then ToText(cDate({?@ReportStartDate}), "MM/dd/yyyy") + " - " + ToText(cDate({?@ReportEndDate}), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

When I use this my report does not work and I get just a blank page.

How can I get the `yyyyMMdd` format converted to `MM/dd/yyyy` format within the Formula Field?

Comment: You will need to add this conversion into a separate field and then display the same field where you are showing this formula.

Comment: what are the data types of  IsPaid, StartDate and EndDate? And more important are you sure that IsPaid has "true" value?